# Objective C - creating concrete class instances from base class depending upon type

Tags: objective-c, ios, oop

Just to give a real world example, say the base class is Vehicle and concrete classes are TwoWheeler and FourWheeler. Now the type of the vehicle - TwoWheeler or FourWheeler, is decided by the base class Vehicle. When I create an instance of TwoWheeler/FourWheeler using alloc-init method, it calls the super implementation like below to set the value of common properties defined in the Vehicle class and out of these properties one of them is type that actually decides if the type is TwoWheeler or FourWheeler.

```
   if (self = [super initWithDictionary:dict]){
     [self setOtherAttributes:dict]; 
      return self; 
    }
```

Now when I get a collection of vehicles some of them could be TwoWheeler and others will be FourWheeler. Hence I cannot directly create an instance of TwoWheeler or FourWheeler like this

```
Vehicle *v = [[TwoWheeler alloc] initWithDictionary:dict];
```

Is there any way I can create an instance of base class and once I know the type, create an instance of child class depending upon type and return it. With the current implementation, it would result in infinite loop because I call super implementation from concrete class.

What would be the perfect design to handle this scenario when I don't know which concrete class should be instantiated beforehand?

Comment: So you wantba some special setter methods that conditionally change the class of your object?

Comment: Why would you let your base class decide the type, the base class shouldnt even know the type!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generally this is done with a [Factory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern).

If you want the factory to be part of the base class, that's fine but it may cause issues in the future. In Objective C, class methods make good factories.

```
+ (Vehicle *)vehicleWithDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dict
{
    if ([[dict objectForKey:kVehicleType] isEqualToString:@"TwoWheeler"]) {
        return [[[TwoWheeler alloc] initWithDictionary:dict] autorelease];
    } else if ([[dict objectForKey:kVehicleType] isEqualToString @"FourWheeler"]) {
        return [[[FourWheeler alloc] initWithDictionary:dict] autorelease];
    } else {
        return [[[Vehicle alloc] initWithDictionary:dict] autorelease];
    }
}
```

The factory can be part of the Vehicle class and used as so.

```
// Instead of [[Vehicle alloc] initWithDictionary:dict]
Vehicle *vehicle = [Vehicle vehicleWithDictionary:dict];
```

---

**Update**

I came up with a way to do what was asked. Let it serve as a shining example of why it's such a bad idea and why you should never do it.

```
- (id)initWithDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dict
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        // If override is in the dictionary, then it mustn't try to call the subclass.
        if (![dict objectForKey:kOverride]) {
            NSMutableDictionary *overrideDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:dict];
            [overrideDict setObject:@"override" forKey:kOverride];

            if ([[dict objectForKey:kVehicleType] isEqualToString:@"TwoWheeler"]) {
                [self release];
                return [[[TwoWheeler alloc] initWithDictionary:overrideDict] autorelease];
            } else if ([[dict objectForKey:kVehicleType] isEqualToString @"FourWheeler"]) {
                [self release];
                return [[[FourWheeler alloc] initWithDictionary:overrideDict] autorelease];
            }
        }

        // init as normal
    }

    return self;
}
```

Comment: Thanks jeff for the reply. As a workaround, I am doing the same thing currently. But wondering if without knowing type beforehand it can be done? The Vehicle class determines the type actually.

Comment: `... == @"TwoWheller` and `... == @"FourWheller` are not wise. They should be `[[dict objectForKey:kVehicleType] isEqualToString:@"TwoWheeler"]`.

Comment: @BenedictCohen ops… err… I have no idea what you are talking about. It was always `-isEqualToString:` <_< … >_>

Comment: @JefferyThomas was the return type always missing too? ;-)

Comment: @indiantroy It's not a workaround, it's the way to do it. You asked if vehicle can know how to create the proper subclass. This is how it's done.

Comment: @indiantroy If you want to know if it's possible, it is. I wrote up an idea for how to do it, but I hope it only goes to show why it's such a bad idea.

Comment: @JefferyThomas, where do you write this - (id)initWithDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dict method? In Vehicle class?

Comment: @indiantroy Nowhere! It's a bad idea! Use the factory version. The factory version can be a part of the Vehicle class.

Comment: @JefferyThomas: It's worth noting that class clusters (i.e. the pattern you think is a bad idea) is a very common idiom in Cocoa, used by many of the Foundation types (e.g. `NSString`, `NSArray`, etc.) Factories are quite a foreign concept, one that I have not seen employed by Apple in many (any?) places.

Comment: @SedateAlien Class clusters are useful. They can adapt performance characteristics to suit the current needs of data which may change over the lifetime of an object. That is not the problem indiantroy is trying to solve, and doesn't need the additional complexity involved with that solution. A factory suits this problem nicely.

Answer (score 2):

you should use abstract factory As following, the class Vehicle will have a method called, createInstance, this method will have a parameter that will decide what to create consider the example

```
+ (Vehicle*) createInstance:(int)numberOfWheels
{
    if(numberOfWheels == 2)
    {
        return [[TwoWheeler alloc] init];
    }
    else
    {
        return [[FourWheeler alloc] init];
    }

    return nil;
}
```

You would call it like this

```
Vehicle *v = [Vehicle createInstance:2];
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "Your base class shouldnt know what the type of the subclasses are" given that you're showing code in which the base class (Vehicle) references the subclasses (TwoWheeler and FourWheeler).

Comment: yes u r correct, i have not written a good sentence above will update it